# C running slower than PyPy

Tags: python, c

I'm running these two codes. They both perform the same mathematical procedure (calculate series value up to large terms), and also, as expected, produce the same output.

But for some reason, the PyPy code is running significantly faster than the C code.

I cannot figure out why this is happening, as I expected the C code to run faster.

I'd be thankful if anyone could help me by clarifying that (maybe there is a better way to write the C code?)

---

**C code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double Sum = 0.0;
    long n;

    for(n = 2; n < 1000000000; n = n + 1) {
        double Sign;
        Sign = pow(-1.0, n % 2);        

        double N;
        N = (double) n;

        double Sqrt;
        Sqrt = sqrt(N);

        double InvSqrt;
        InvSqrt = 1.0 / Sqrt;

        double Ln;
        Ln = log(N);

        double LnSq;
        LnSq = pow(Ln, 2.0);

        double Term;
        Term = Sign * InvSqrt * LnSq;


        Sum = Sum + Term;
    }


    double Coeff;
    Coeff = Sum / 2.0;
    printf("%0.14f \n", Coeff);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**PyPy code (faster implementation of Python):**

```
from math import log, sqrt

Sum = 0

for n in range(2, 1000000000):
    Sum += ((-1)**(n % 2) * (log(n))**2) / sqrt(n)

print(Sum / 2)
```

Comment: what is the optimization level you used to compiler the C code?

Comment: I’m compiling it and running through the terminal. Simply using “make” then “./” . No optimization level, I guess.

Comment: Don't use the slow `pow()` for powers of int.

Comment: @Yunnosch what do you recommend me to use? The need of using pow() was to get a sign altering summation (+,-,+, ... ).

Comment: @LeonardoBohac Most simple approach: `n % 2 ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: How about not using so many variables?

Comment: Without optimisation, you are definitely not running the equivalent instructions. In the Python case you never compute the inverse square root, you divide the term by the square root before adding it to the sum. That is one of those things, that unless optimised away add to slightly different runtime behaviour.

Comment: `pow(x, 2.0)` is easier and especially more efficiently written as `x*x` as well...

Comment: @Aconcagua I changed the line " Sign = pow(-1.0,n%2); " to " Sign = n % 2 ? -1 : 1; " . It ran a little faster, thanks.

Comment: @Aconcagua also changed " pow(Ln,2) " to " Ln * Ln ". Ran significantly faster ! Thanks again

Comment: with optimization turned on, the C code runs twice as fast.

Comment: @Sedo The number of variables is the one thing that is absolutely not a problem in this code. Any modern compiler would convert the code to SSA *anyway*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to compiler's optimisation level, you can improve your code as well:

```
int main()
{
    double Sum = 0.0;
    long n;
    for(n = 2; n < 1000000000; ++n)
    {
        double N = n; // cast is implicit, only for code readability, no effect on runtime!

        double Sqrt = sqrt(N);

        //double InvSqrt;     // spare that:
        //InvSqrt = 1.0/Sqrt; // you spare this division with!

        double Ln = log(N);
        double LnSq;
        //LnSq = pow(Ln,2.0);
        LnSq = Ln*Ln; // more efficient

        double Term;
        //Term = Sign * InvSqrt * LnSq;
        Term = LnSq / Sqrt;

        if(n % 2)
            Term = -Term; // just negating, no multiplication
                          // (IEEE provided: just one bit inverted)

        Sum = Sum + Term;
    }
// ...
```

Now we can simplify the code a little more:

```
int main()
{
    double Sum = 0.0;
    for(long n = 2; n < 1000000000; ++n)
    //  ^^^^ possible since C99, better scope, no runtime effect  
    {
        double N = n;
        double Ln = log(N);
        double Term = Ln * Ln / sqrt(N);

        if(n % 2)
            Sum -= Term;
        else
            Sum += Term;
    }
// ...
```

Comment: It is running significantly faster than my old code. But it’s not running faster than when I just changed the pow(Ln,2) to Ln*Ln, as you suggested. Thank you very much though. I’ll mark as “answered”, run a few more tests and let you know if something goes wrong.

Comment: @LeonardoBohac Well, I threw out both calls to `pow`. `pow` is rather expensive, so you'll notice quickly. Sparing the single multiplication (`x/y` vs `z=1.0/y; x*z`) is only peanuts, especially as the remaining work to be done is relatively large compared to (`log` + `sqrt`), so you might have difficulties to notice at all (similar the other propositions), still there *is* some gain yet...

Answer (score 4):

This is far from surprising, `PyPy` does a number of run-time optimizations by default, where as `C` compilers by default do not perform any optimization. Dave Beazley's [2012 PyCon Keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_-5XZzJyt0) covers this pretty explicitly and provides an deep explanation of why this happens.

Per the referenced talk, `C` should surpass `PyPy` when compiled with [optimization level](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) `2` or `3` (you can watch the full section on the performance of fibonacci generation in `cpython`, `pypy` and `C` starting [here](https://youtu.be/6_-5XZzJyt0?t=17m58s)).

Comment: Well, he is calling `pow(3)`, which is a library function.... very good integration must have the compiler to _unroll_ `pow()` into a negation.  In python, it's an operator, so the interpreter can well look at the operators and decide what to do...  only with the overhead of the function calls involved, it's enough to justify a doubling in time, or more.